# How to fix "type argument S is not within bounds of type-variable E" in Java

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying make polymorphic access to different Enum classes by defining some base access method using interfaces. For example:

```
package com.company;

public interface StatesInterface<E extends Enum<E>> {

    E getOneState();
    E getTwoState();
    E getThreeState();
}
```

And some implementation:

```
package com.company;

public enum States implements StatesInterface<States> {

    ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR;

    @Override
    public States getOneState() {
        return ONE;
    }
    @Override
    public States getTwoState() {
        return TWO;
    }
    @Override
    public States getThreeState() {
        return THREE;
    }
}
```

Note: I know that this code has problem because interface provides static enum values via non-static interface, but I don't have any idea how to solve it.

When I'm trying to use this interface as type constraint in classes, I have got type errors. For example:

```
package com.company;

public class Lifecycle<S extends StatesInterface> {

    private S state;

    public void transit() {
        state = state.getOneState(); // <---- incompatible types
    }
}
```

In this case I can't assign `state.getOneState();` of type `Enum` to `state` of type `StatesInterface<Enum>`.

When I try to change generic type to `Lifecycle<S extends StatesInterface<S>>` compiles says me `Error:(3, 50) java: type argument S is not within bounds of type-variable E`.

My goal is make a set of different Enum classes with common interface for creating a new classes that generalize class `Lifecycle` to a specific Enum type.

Is it possible to achieve this using provided code and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is this:

```
class Lifecycle<S extends Enum<S> & StatesInterface<S>>
```

---

In comparison, with your definitions like this:

```
interface StatesInterface<E extends Enum<E>>

enum States implements StatesInterface<States>

class Lifecycle<S extends StatesInterface>
```

then `getOneState()` just returns a type `Object extends Enum<Object>`, because you were using the **raw type** for `StatesInterface` by not giving it type parameters, which is not compatible with the type `S extends StatesInterface`, thus giving you the `"Type mismatch: cannot convert from Enum to S"`

By changing your definition to `class Lifecycle<S extends Enum<S> & StatesInterface<S>>` you allow `getOneState()` to return `S extends Enum<S> & StatesInterface<S>` which is of course compatible to be set into a variable of type `S`, `S state = getOneState()`

---

**What to take away from this**

You should [strive to avoid using raw types](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=224) because they forgo the type safety of generics and also just wont play nice with other generics in general, as you have experienced here.

Comment: Thanks! This is fix my problem.

Comment: Rather than just giving the solution, it would be worth if you can elaborate it a bit more.

Comment: @RavindraRanwala was working on it, the explanation takes a bit of time and I wanted to at least get OP an answer sooner rather than later. How does this explanation look to you?